# Unity 5.0 : how can change unity ui button image

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i want to change image of Ui.Button in unity via script i am very new to unity development

i have a button i am accesing like this

level2 is my button in Ui

```html
level2 = GameObject.Find ("level2").GetComponent<Button> ();
```

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Image myButtonImage; // Assign /Initilize from Editor or code
private Button level2;

void Start ()
{
    level2 = GameObject.Find ("level2").GetComponent<Button> ();
    level2.image = myButtonImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change image button sprite(Source Image)

```
public Sprite sp1;
public Button level2;

void Start(){
     level2 = GameObject.Find ("level2").GetComponent<Button> ();
     level2.image.sprite = sp1;
}
```